# Number of ways a committee can be formed from $4$ single men, $4$ single women, and a married couple subject to the given restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A committee is to be formed from a group of $10$ people consisting of $4$ single men, $4$ single women and a married couple. The committee is to consist of a chairman, who must be a single man, $2$ other men and $2$ women.

(i) Find the number of ways in which the committee can be formed.

(ii) How many of these ways include the married couple?

My answers:

(i) $5C1 \times 4C2 \times 5C2 = 300$

(ii) Not very sure.

Is my part (i) answer correct? How should I do part (ii)?  Thanks

Comment: No, your answer to $(i)$ is not correct.  There are $4$ choices for the chairman, not $5$.

Comment: For (ii), try answering the easier question of "how many *don't* include the married couple."  See how that answer relates to the answer you are after.

Comment: why the man in the married couple is not included for (i)?

Comment: Hmm?  He is though... Count the committees by: Choose a single man to be chairman (4 options), choose two more men from among any remaining men single or otherwise (4 choose 2 options), choose two more women from among any remaining women single or otherwise (5 choose 2 options)

Comment: Why is the man from the married couple not eligible to be chairman?  From the problem statement: "*The committee is to consist of a chairman,* **who must be a single man** (i.e. not married), *2 other men and 2 women*"

Comment: Ohhh...I got it. Did  not read carefully..

Comment: So for part (ii) , am I correct to say 240 (found in i) subtract (4C1 * 3C2 * 4C2) = 168 ?

Comment: Your answer for part (ii) is incorrect.  There was a misleading comment above.  A direct count is the easiest approach.  To count indirectly, you would have to exclude any committee which includes neither member of the married couple or exactly one member of the married couple.

Comment: If I count directly to include the married couple in (ii) I got 4C2 (choose 1 chairman from 4 single men and 1 other man) * 4C1 (choose 1 other woman from the 4 single woman) * 1 (1 way to include the couple) = 24. Am I correct?

Comment: Until your question has been answered, you should feel free to edit your question to show your revised attempts given the feedback you have received in the comments.  You should not change the question after it has been answered since that may invalidate the answers you have already received.  Also, explaining how you obtained your answer helps readers detect any errors you may have made.

Answer (score 1):

> A committee is to be formed from a group of $10$ people consisting of $4$ single men, $4$ single women and a married couple. The committee is to consist of a chairman, who must be a single man, $2$ other men and $2$ women.

There seems to be an implicit assumption here that the married couple is heterosexual, so we have a total of five men and five women.  Moreover, there are four single people and one married person of each sex.

> Find the number of ways in which the committee can be formed.

As JMoravitz pointed out in the comments, you overlooked the requirement that the chairperson of the committee be a single man.

There are four ways to select the chairperson from among the single men.  That leaves four men from which to select the other two male members of the committee and five women from which to select the two female members of the committee.  Hence, the number of committees which can be formed is
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2} = 240$$

> How many of these ways include the married couple?

**Method 1:**  We will count directly.

If both members of the married couple serve on the committee, then we are left with three positions to fill, the chairperson, the other male position, and the other female position.  There are four ways to select the chairperson from among the single men, three ways to select the other male member of the committee from among the other three single men, and four ways to pick the other female member of the committee from among the four single women.  Hence, there are $$4 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = 48$$ committees which can be formed which include both members of the married couple.

**Method 2:** We correct your attempt in the comments. You wrote:

> If I count directly to include the married couple in (ii) I got $4C2$ (choose $1$ chairman from $4$ single men and $1$ other man) * $4C1$ (choose $1$ other woman from the $4$ single woman) * $1$ ($1$ way to include the couple) $= 24$.

The reason your attempt in the comments is incorrect is that you forgot to distinguish between the chairperson and the other single man on the committee.  Since there are two ways to select the chairperson from among the two single men on the committee, you should have had
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{2} = 48$$
where the additional factor $\binom{2}{1}$ counts the number of ways you could have selected the chairperson from among the two single men selected to serve on the committee.

**Method 3:**  It was suggested in the comments that you count arrangements which do not include the married couple.  This was not good advice since it it easier to make a direct count.

We can confirm that there are $48$ committees which include the married couple by subtracting the number of committees in which at least one member of the married couple does not serve from the total number of committees.

We found the total number of committees in the first part of the question.

*Neither member of the married couple serves on the committee*:  We must select the chairperson from among the four single men, select two of the other three single men to serve on the committee, and two of the four single women to serve on the committee.  There are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$
such committees.

*The married man serves on the committee but his wife does not*:  That leaves four positions to fill, the chairperson, the other male position on the committee, and the two female positions. We must select the chairperson from among the four single men, the other male member of the committee from among the other three single men, and two of the four single women to serve on the committee.  There are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
such committees.

*The married woman serves on the committee, but her husband does not*:  That leaves four positions to fill, the chairperson, the other two male positions, and the other female position. We must select the chairperson from among the four single men, the other two male positions from among the other three single men, and one of the four single women to serve on the committee.  There are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$
such committees.

Hence, the number of committees which include both members of the married couple is
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1} = 48$$